# Не могу подключить Emmet на NetBeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans, emmet

На оф. сайте emmet и на его гитхабе написано, что могу подключить через Tools > Plugins > Available plugins. Но у меня там его нет, а так чтобы скачать nbm-файл, то можно только для 7-ых версий NetBeans.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить

Comment: Никак не решить, только если сами не возьмётесь за разработку своего плугина для нетбинс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключил версию плагина для 7.4 после рестарта работаем как обычно с Emmet только надо нажимать не tab а ctrl+Alt+N

Answer (score 2):

Скачать последнюю версию плагина можно по ссылке http://download.emmet.io/org-lorenzos-emmet.nbm (*источник:* https://github.com/emmetio/netbeans/issues/3#issuecomment-51111558)

Затем в netbeans выбрать: `Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add Plugins... > выбираем скачанный файл > Install > Перезапускаем Netbeans.`